# The slot for "plotOrder" comes up as 1 instead of a vector with length specific to my data

Tags: r, sp, spdep

My goal is to find neighbors from my SpatialPolygons object using the `poly2nb()` command from the `sp` package in R.

This is my code thus far:

```
   p <- s_gis %>%
   select(long, lat) %>%
   Polygon()
   ps <- Polygons(list(p), 1000)
   sps <- SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
```

where s_gis is my dataset. I'm otherwise able to make a successful SpatialPolygons object except for the fact that the slot for plotOrder reads 1, instead of 636353 like it is in my dataset.

Running the `poly2nb()` commands returns an error `Error in sp$mbxv[i]:(n * 2) : argument of length 0` which I'm assuming is coming from the fact that it's finding 0 neighbors given that I only have a plotOrder of 1.

How do I modify the plotOrder?

In addition, regarding my error message from the `poly2nb()` command, if the problem runs deeper, can someone shed some insight as to why?

I have also tried `ps@plotOrder <- s_gis$order` to no avail.

EDIT:

```
#get lat, long, and groupid
s_gis_latlon <- s_gis %>%
  select(long,lat, group)

#group lists by group id
p_groups <- split(s_gis_latlon, s_gis_latlon$group)

#delete group id so that we can have 2-column matrix for Polygon
p_groups1 <- lapply(p_groups, function(x) { x[,3] <- NULL; x })

# turn each element of list into a polygon
p_groups1 <- lapply(names(p_groups1),
                    function(x) {b <- Polygon(p_groups1[[x]])
                            b
                       }) 

#turn list of polygons into Polygons
ps <- Polygons(p_groups1,1)

data <- s_gis %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(district_wealthrange = mean(wealthrange))

#create SpatialPolygons object
sps <- SpatialPolygons(ps@Polygons)
```

I'm getting the error `Error in SpatialPolygons(ps@Polygons) : 
  no slot of name "Polygons" for this object of class "Polygon"`

Comment: What's `s_gis`? Can you  show us its summary() and maybe its head()? What does `sps` end up as? Is it one polygon or many? How are you running `poly2nb` to get that error? What are you running it on? On `sps`? Do you  care about the plot order or working out the neighbourhood?

Comment: s_gis is one of the datasets I'm using. The summary is quite large; however, I did select out long and lat which results in a tibble with dimensions 661228 x 2. sps ends up `Slot "plotOrder":
[1] 1

Slot "labpt":
[1] 76.83899 29.49845

Slot "ID":
[1] "1000"

Slot "area":
[1] 196.6975

Slot "coords":
# I removed these to save char. space
Slot "plotOrder":
[1] 1

Slot "bbox":
        min      max
x 68.186249 97.41529
y  6.755953 37.07827

Slot "proj4string":
CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 `

Comment: I'm runnning `poly2nb(sps, queen = FALSE)` and I care more about working out the neighborhood. Thanks so much for your quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we know enough to reproduce your error message, I'll do that with a data frame of lat-long numbers:

```
> library(sp)
> s_gis = data.frame(long=runif(5), lat=runif(5))
```

that should be equivalent to your `s_gis` with lat-long selected. Continue with your code to make `sps`:

```
> p = Polygon(s_gis)
> ps = Polygons(list(p), 1000)
> sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
```

and now use the `spdep` package:

```
> library(spdep)
Loading required package: Matrix
> poly2nb(sps, queen=FALSE)
Error in sp$mbxv[i]:(n * 2) : argument of length 0
>
```

and there's your error.

`poly2nb` computes the adjacency matrix between polygons. How many polygons have you got?

```
> length(sps)
[1] 1
> plot(sps)
```

[image]

One! (although it looks a bit like two but that's because the random lines cross over. This is one ring). No wonder it failed! This data is simply a set of point coordinates in each row - how do you think this data frame could define more than one polygon?

Comment: I've edited my original question. I've tried grouping my coordinates by a group id (which corresponds to each polygon). However, I'm getting a strange lists within a list issue when I make my SpatialPolygon object. The correct plot order is in my `sps` object; however, it's nested within a list which I can't seem to index. Thus, `poly2nb()` is still returning the same error message since it's not seeing the plot order and consequently not seeing the correct list of multiple polygon objects that I have.

Comment: You've completely changed the question now. I answered your question about the error you were getting from poly2nb (which didn't even relate to the *title* about the plot order, but never mind) and now you've added a load of stuff that gives a *different* error, you've still not shown us some sample data to make a reproducible answer, and I suspect you've left out some important packages necessary to make your code run. I would revert your edits, mark my answer as an answer, and create a new question with your new code, some sample data, and your new error message.